# Why do I not need to use new keyword in ContentPlaceHolder class in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

In ASP.NET, having a MasterPage and using C#, I can use `ContentPlaceHolder` with or without the `new` keyword and the quantity of method and properties from this class are the same.

I.e, both

```
ContentPlaceHolder ctph;
```

and

```
ContentPlaceHolder ctph = new ContenPlanceHolder();
```

have the same methods and properties. I don't understand why I can use the `ctph` variable without the new keyword.

Comment: Do you have a `ContenPlaceHolder` control placed on your MasterPage with the id of `ctph`?

Comment: No, ctph is on a separate page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ContentPlaceHolder ctph;
```

`ctph` has the value `default(ContentPlaceHolder)`.  for a reference type this will be `null`.  For a value type this will be a valid object with all fields default initialized.

`ContentPlaceHolder` is a reference type, so, when you say:

> Has the same methods and properties.

Well, yeah, because those are defined by the *type*.  Are you determining this via Intellisense?  Umm... don't.  Try calling a method and see what happens.

Comment: @user1462042: Intellisense is not a debugging tool, it is an autocomplete feature.  You cannot assume that your object is in a valid state because intellisense shows that it has available methods.  How could it possibly know what the value of your variable will be *at runtime*? It can't, it makes no sense.

Comment: @user1462042L: [This is what you use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) to reason about the behavior of your program, not intellisense.

Comment: Ok, I called FindControl. ContentPlaceHolder ctph; 
            ctph = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("MainContent");
            HtmlTableCell tt; tt = (HtmlTableCell)ctph.FindControl("td"); works OK, no runtime errors

Comment: *"works OK, no runtime errors"* ...right, because; `ctph = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("MainContent");`.  You just assigned it a new value!  You never used it when it was null, but I assure you, it was null right after `ContentPlaceHolder ctph;`.  You may as well just have declared and assigned it in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, but can you do it at runtime?

Intellisense (spelling?) is a purely compile time construct, it doesn't know that your first example is going to be null at runtime and throw an exception. It just lists metadata based methods and properties ect.

Comment: No errors, no warnings, no exception throws. It works ok without "new"

Comment: @user1462042 Can you show us an example of code that successfully calls a method on `ctph` without instantiating it?

Comment: @user1462042 I doubt that very much, as it is a class per: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.contentplaceholder.aspx

Comment: @user1462042: You have a flawed notion of what the word "works" means. Compiles != works.

Comment: ContentPlaceHolder ctph;                                           ctph = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("MainContent");// Works OK!

Comment: HtmlTableCell tt;  tt = (HtmlTableCell)ctph.FindControl("td"+i);// Works ok.